# certain android emulator/api combinations skew background drawables

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-drawable

My custom background drawables appear to be skewed slightly in the nexus 7/10 emulator skin that comes with the android sdk, if the emulator is running api10.  Api10 appears to be working fine in other emulators, as does api14+ in the nexus10 emulator.
UPDATE: this also occurs with the WXGA Tablet emulator under api 21.

How it should look on api 10+ for all emulators:
[image]
How it looks on api10 with the nexus7/10 emulators:
[image]

Here is a description of what I have tested:

1. Nexus10 emulator, api10:   skewed buttons
2. Nexus7 emulator, api10:    skewed buttons
3. Nexus10 emulator, api14:   buttons are ok
4. Nexus10 emulator, api19:   buttons are ok
5. Nexus One WVGA emulator, api10: buttons are ok
6. WXGA tablet emulator 10", api21: skewed buttons

Here is the xml drawable code for the button background:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:state_pressed="true" >
        <shape android:shape="rectangle"  >
            <corners android:radius="8dp" />
            <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#ff00b4ff" />
            <gradient android:angle="-90" android:startColor="#ff00a8eb" android:endColor="#ff00b7ff"  />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:state_enabled="false" >
        <shape android:shape="rectangle"  >
            <corners android:radius="8dp" />
            <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#ff00b4ff" />
            <solid android:color="#ff0098d5"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item >
        <shape android:shape="rectangle"  >
            <corners android:radius="8dp" />
            <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#ff00b4ff" />
            <gradient android:angle="-90" android:startColor="#ff00b7ff" android:endColor="#ff00a8eb" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

And here is the xml in the layout file for the load level button:

```
<Button
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/title_button_width_column2"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/load_level_button"
            android:id="@+id/loadGameButton"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/infinitePlayButtonWrapper"
            android:layout_toRightOf ="@+id/infinitePlayButtonWrapper"
            android:layout_toEndOf ="@+id/infinitePlayButtonWrapper"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded_button_lightblue_menu"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:textSize="@dimen/title_button_text_size"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:onClick="loadLevelClicked"
            android:gravity="left"/>
```

Does anyone know why the background might be skewed like that?  Is it an xhdpi + api10 issue perhaps?

Comment: Nexus 7 or 10 physical devices never ran API 10. Find a Gingerbread device and use that for testing. There shouldn't be any tablets on API 10, except maybe the original Galaxy Tab, and that was a *mess*.

Comment: Despite Tab being an API8 machine, I should just test on tablets with API11+ then?  Any idea how many other tablets used pre-v11 apis by chance?

Comment: Honeycomb (API11) was Androids official entrance into the tablet game, but realistically API12 is where you still might find some tablets. Oh, and the original Kindle Fire was based on 2.3.4, which is API 10 -- I'm unclear whether Amazon pushed upgrades to those, and I don't have one handy here to check. The [Dashboard](https://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html) doesn't show any Honeycomb devices, and I usually aim at API15+ for tablet support. Adding 10% of development effort to hit another 0.5% of devices isn't economical for me.